# how to create dynamic type/scheme in Graphql at runtime (javascript)

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Is there a way to create dynamic type/scheme in Graphql at runtime?

for example:
if currentlly I have only ‘people’ type with fields:
name,
age.

```
client can run a Graphql query as below:

    query {
      people(id: "1") {
        name
        age
      }
    }
```

I want client to be able to run a Graphql query about Vehicles with fields:
name,
model

I want to do it in 2 steps: 
**step 1:**
client will send a new JsonSchema (through rest api)

**step2:**

```
client will be able to run a Graphql query about Vehicles as below:
query {
  vehicle(id: "1") {
    name
    model
  }
}
```

***all should be at run time (without compile/restart application)***

Comment: i don't think this makes sense. Because you do not know in advance how the query should be resolved.

Comment: Hi @Locco0_0 , I need it to have the abillity of add entities to my db and then be able to query them in GraphQL query. (resolve will be default without any data manipulations). Do you have another idea of how shoud I do it?

Comment: It depends if you know if there are a limited amount of entities. Maybe you could add a name property to your entity and save the properties of the entity as a json string. Then you could have just one query which gives you the name and the json string.

Comment: there are no limited amounts of entities. think about it as an application that have 100 entities (just for example), client can run query only about those 100 entities. if I will add one more entity to DB , client won't be able to run a query about it (because there is no GraphQL type for this new entity). so I want client to have the abillity to add this type to GraphQL (on run time). does this make any sense?

Comment: I don't think that you can reload the schema without reloading the server. But i'm not sure about that. You might want to try the way i described with a entity saved as a json string.